# Hard triangles on cycles render 2.79

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have smooth shading, and it works in any mode except in render:
[image]
(left render mode, right material mode)
Im using cycles and blender 2.79.
I tried switching all faces/edges/vertices to smooth manually and not working.

Comment: Do you have normal map in your shader node?

Comment: @FFeller yes I have, thats how it look: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/600020090087276544/643500831533957150/unknown.png

Comment: That can cause artifacts like this. Render a picture without it, and if it fix the problem try to adjust the normal's settings.

Comment: Yeah without normal artifacts dissapeared, but what settings should I adjust?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know. Try to decrease the strenght, but there are no too many options, you can try the bruteforce. Or may be modify your question, now you know what causes the problem.